# Doubly linked list: swap two adjacent nodes without a temp variable

Tags: doubly-linked-list

This code is C++ - in so much as it uses classes/objects. In reality it is all just C, since I was playing around, implementing a doubly linked list without using the STL.

The language shouldn't matter. What is bothering me is that I used a temporary variable.

Can anyone improve this code so that no temporary variable is needed? It is a simple bubble sort, but what concerns me is swapping two adjacent nodes of a doubly linked list.

```
class LinkedListItem *linkedListItem;
bool swapped;

do
{
  swapped = false;

  for (linkedListItem = uniqueWords.GetHead();
       linkedListItem != NULL;
       linkedListItem = linkedListItem->GetNext())
  {
     if (linkedListItem->GetNext() != NULL)
     {
         if (linkedListItem->GetWordCount() < linkedListItem->GetNext()->GetWordCount())
         {
            // Swap items to bubble smaller value up.

            // Rats!! I can't seem to do it by juggling pointers without a temp variable :-(
            // ToDo: figure out how!
            class LinkedListItem *itemAfterNext;
            if (linkedListItem->GetNext() == NULL)
               itemAfterNext = NULL;
            else
               itemAfterNext = linkedListItem->GetNext()->GetNext();

            if (uniqueWords.GetHead() == linkedListItem)
               uniqueWords.SetHead(linkedListItem->GetNext());

            if (uniqueWords.GetTail() == linkedListItem->GetNext())
               uniqueWords.SetTail(linkedListItem);

////--------- start swap -----------  
            if (linkedListItem->GetPrev() != NULL)
                linkedListItem->GetPrev()->SetNext(linkedListItem->GetNext());

            if (linkedListItem->GetNext()->GetNext() != NULL)
                linkedListItem->GetNext()->GetNext()->SetPrev(linkedListItem);

                 linkedListItem->GetNext()->SetPrev(linkedListItem->GetPrev());
            linkedListItem->GetNext()->SetNext(linkedListItem);

            linkedListItem->SetPrev(linkedListItem->GetNext());
            linkedListItem->SetNext(itemAfterNext);
////--------- end swap -----------

            swapped = true;
         }
     }
   }
} while (swapped == true);
```

Comment: If this is "working" code then [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better fit than SO.

Comment: You cannot swap two items without using a temporary variable. In some rare cases, [XOR swapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) can be used to swap two numbers, but I'd really advice you not to do (see reference for reasons). In most cases a temp-swap is more efficient anyway.

Comment: Though, you could improve your code by introducing a proper ``swap()`` method that encapsulates your swapping process.

Comment: @user1438038, I _think_ that I can. I know of nodes A, B, C, D where I want to swap B & C. Even if at some monent, one is not directly linked to another, I can still (hopefully) recreate it if I follow a convoluted trail that "links to alink that links to .." - which is where I struggled and introdcued the temporary variable.  @ user1438038 agreed, but that is not the issue here. Given that I introduce a swap() method, how do I do it without a temporary variable?